# Android right to left NavigationDrawer menu items aren't RTL

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, right-to-left, navigation-drawer

I need to align navigation menu items to the right.
I read many articles and questions and answers but i couldn't find what's wrong in my project.
This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="right">

<include
    layout="@layout/content_activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_activity_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

This is **activity_home_drawer.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="حساب کاربری" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sign_out"
        android:title="خروج از حساب" />
</group>
```

I can make drawer itself to open from right but elements of NavigationView still remain left to right. You can see the result here:

[image]

As you see menu items aren't right to left. How to make them rtl?

Comment: I add this code to my app but i am getting this error:
"No drawer view found with gravity LEFT"

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 send me your code to fix it

Comment: I add Direction RTL to my drawer and it open from right now :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try adding   android:layoutDirection="rtl"

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

This works for api level 17 or above. For older devices there is a trick.
In application level of android manifest set ***supportRtl="false"*** and in layouts set ***layout_gravity="right"***. This works properly.

Answer (score 0):

> First delete app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" and in
>   "@layout/nav_header_main" layout you can set custom layout.in the below you can see content of nav_header_main layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:background="@drawable/banner"
        android:gravity="right">



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```